# Powershell data file name

Tags: powershell

I need to open an excel file, refresh the content and save it in another path.
So this script work:

```
$file = 'C:\Scripts\Spreadsheet.xlsx'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $false
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy")
$filename = 'C:\Scripts\Spreadsheet ' + $enddate + '.xlsx'
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
$wb.RefreshAll()
$wb.SaveAs($filename)
$wb.Close()
$x1.Quit()
Remove-Variable wb,x1*
```

But I also need the time in the file name.
So I've replaced the content of $enddate with

```
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss")
```

If I run the script I get an error about the $filename variable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy HH mm ss")
```